# Wake on Lan (WOL) stopped working

Tags: local-area-network, bios, wake-on-lan

My wake on lan stopped working for no apaprent reason.

I installed wireshark and from another machine sent a magic packet to the target computer and I could see the packet was coming through.  Nothing in the BIOS changes, so

Answer (score 0):

I installed wireshark and from another machine sent a magic packet to the target computer and I could see the packet was coming through.

No changes were made to the BIOS, however after resetting the CMOS WOL started working again.

To reset the CMOS, check your motherboard manual.  First take some pictures of your current BIOS setting in case you need it later.  To reset the CMOS usually involves the following:

1. Unplugging the power from your machine (important!!!)
2. Moving jumper pins on your motherboard from pins 2-3 to pins 1-2 for about 10 seconds.
3. Move the jumper back to pins 2-3.
4. Reboot and reconfigure your BIOS